# How to use track the user selection and present in display Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, selection

I want to track whatever the user selects in the table and present in another form using Angular JS. I am quite stuck on how to perform this activity. My first attempt is to use track by but it does not get called.

user.html

```
<div>
<tr ng-repeat="usrInput in usrInputs |   filter:searchData track by $index" ng-click="clickValidValues()">
    <td>{{usrInput.name}}</td>
    <td><button ng-click="clickValidValues()"> Update </button></td>
 </tr>
</div>
```

Now, Whatever the user selects, I want that data to be presented in the form below.

```
<div>
 <form>
    <input class="form-control" ng-repeat="usrInput in usrInputs" type="text" disabled>
     {{usrInput.name}}
    </input>
</form>
</div>
```

user.js

```
$scope.usrInput = [
        {name: "Mike"},
        {name: "Bir"},
];
```

Comment: Firstly you cannot use ng-model on tr ..On what event you want to show it in the input box and what exactly you want to show?

Comment: @NamdeoKarande, So, I have removed the ng-model. I have two divs; one with table and one with form. The form appears when the user selects Update. When the user selects data from the table, the form appears and whatever the user selected in the table, it should appear in the form. That means there should be a way to track the selected data and present in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for that you can do is -

user.html -

```
<div>
<tr ng-repeat="usrInput in usrInputs |   filter:searchData track by $index" 
 ng-click="clickValidValues()">
<td>{{usrInput.name}}</td>
<td><button ng-click="clickValidValues(usrInput.name})"> Update </button>
</td>
</tr>
</div>

<div>
<form>
  <input class="form-control" ng-repeat="usr in newInputs" 
  ng-model="usr" type="text"disabled>

</input>
</form>
</div>
```

user.js-

```
$scope.newInputs=[];
$scope.usrInput = [
    {name: "Mike"},
    {name: "Bir"},
];

$scope.clickValidValues = function(name){
   $scope.newInputs.push(name);

 }
```

Hope this is what you need add the user names in a new array and repeat that new array.